Cpanel Cron Job not working for everyday day

I have 3 cron jobs in my cpanel, I am hitting APIs with curl, my hourly cron job is working fine but daily cron job is not, monthly is not get to test yet for cron:
You might think there is some error with API, so here's the deal:

I edited the same API and changed its time to minute, the cron job starts working started working
When I hit the API with postman manually it wokrs
also I put the curl command that I put in cron into the live terminal of ssh, it works

It is so weird but I am now irritated, any help?
